# Magento 2 CDN cache

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade, static-content-deploy, cdn

I have enabled CDN for my `Magento 2` store static contents.

But just would like to confirm, will there be any issue , if I run the below commands?

Should I rebuild the CDN cache after running these commands? Please advise.

**Commands**

`cd var/view_preprocessed`
`rm -rf ./*`
`cd ../../pub/static`
`rm -rf ./*`
`cd ../../`
`php/magento setup:upgrade`
`php/magento setup:static-content:deploy`